# A non muslim woman wants to divorce her non muslim husband to marry a muslim, does the muslim man get a sin for breaking up a marriage

Tags: nikah

I am  a muslim man. A woman, a good woman i met before i converted and loved once, has come back into my life. I have not commited fornication and will not. But she wants to leave her unhappy marriage so that she may convert and marry me. Can i allow this to happen? Because in all honesty. I love her still and know that we are already great for eachother and that under the blanket of islam, the marriage would , inshallah, hold firm. I am torn between my lonliness and my respect for allahs covenant of marriage. Please. I need a thourough and accurate judgement. Please. Thank you all. And please, dont judge your brother. I do want to know what is right and not just do what suits me.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: This is not a straight-forward situation. You need to consult the jurisprudence authority in your country. When you say: "can I allow this to happen?", which action are you are referring to? If she gets divorced, you can then marry her after _'iddah_. If she converts, she can no longer stay with her current husband regardless. But if he converts, too, then she remains as his wife. On top of all that, you have the question of seeking someone else's wife. Not a question for an on-line resource.

Comment: This decision ultimately lies with the wife. If she wishes to leave her current husband for you (as long as you do not pressure her) then I do not believe you will be sinned. I also do not agree with @III-AK-III, if the current husband converts then she does **not** have to remain with him. Allah made man and woman as equal, it is her choice.